# TypeError: Object(...)(...).flatMap is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs

Please can you help me to why this error appears?

[image]

```
import { FETCHING_DATA } from '../constants'
import { getDataSuccess, getDataFailure } from './actions'
import getPeople from '../api'

import { from, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
// import 'rxjs'
// import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';

// const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
//   action$.ofType(FETCHING_DATA)
//     .mergeMap(action =>
//       Observable.fromPromise(getPeople())
//         .map(response => getDataSuccess(response))
//         .catch(error => Observable.of(getDataFailure(error)))
//       )

const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(  //fixed
    ofType(FETCHING_DATA),
    mergeMap(action => {
      return from(getPeople())
        .flatMap(payload => [
          {
            type: 'SIGNUP_CONCIERGE_SUCCESS',
            payload
          }
        ])
        .catch(error =>
          of({
            type: 'SIGNUP_CONCIERGE_ERROR',
            payload: { error }
          })
        );
    })
  );

export default fetchUserEpic
```

Comment: chrome - latest version

Comment: what does the returned value from `getPeople()` looks like?

Comment: Its a promise that is returned.........

Comment: You can't really use `flatmap` on promise?
You'll have to use `.then` and use flatmap on the value?
`returnedPromise.then(val => val.flatmap)` like so?

Comment: Could you give an example please as I do not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is example from redux-observable

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCH_USER),
  mergeMap(action => ajax.getJSON(`/api/users/${action.payload}`).pipe(
    map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response)),
    catchError(error => of({
      type: FETCH_USER_REJECTED,
      payload: error.xhr.response,
      error: true
    }))
  ))
);
```

And here is adopted solution

```
import { FETCHING_DATA } from '../constants'
import { getDataSuccess, getDataFailure } from './actions'
import getPeople from '../api'

import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';

const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCHING_DATA),
  mergeMap(() => from(getPeople()).pipe(
    map(getDataSuccess),
    catchError(error => of(getDataFailure(error)))
  ))
);

export default fetchUserEpic;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I now get this error ×
TypeError: Object(...)(...).pipe is not a function. I have pushed the copy to my repo. it is in the the epic.js

Comment: Update answer. Try code bellow line *And here is adopted solution*